# merge wp rest api query to get posts per category does not work

Tags: ajax, jquery, rest-api, json

the query the query is working very well 
`http://solucase.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=38`
 but when i add it to loop function to get all post related to the category i receive this error when i check link technology for example

```
function postsPerCat(cat_id) {

    $.ajax({
        method : 'GET',
        dataType : 'json',
        success : 'success',
        url : "http://solucase.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories='cat_id'",
    })
    .then(function (posts) {
        $.each(
            posts,
            function(key, val) {
                $('.recentposts')
                    .append(
                        '<div  class="post"  data-icon="false" onclick=postDetails('
                            + val.id
                            + ')><a   href="#postview"><img src='
                            + val._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']['0'].media_details.sizes.thumbnail.source_url
                            + ' ></img></a><h1 class="post_h1">'
                            + val.title.rendered
                            + '</h1></div>'
                    )
                ;

                $('.recentposts').listview('refresh');
            }
        );
    });

}
```

[image]

Comment: please past your code here directly in place of the image.

Comment: i'm sorry, i didn't read the instructions

Comment: Your category URL includes the quotes, and that parameter expects an Integer, not a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the URL in the error:

```
http://solucase.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=%27cat_id%27
```

`%27` is the URL encoded character for `'`, so you can see what's happening is that in the URL you are requesting with AJAX `cat_id` is not being replaced with the variable value.

This is because the way you have used quotes when defining the URL is incorrect:

```
"http://solucase.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories='cat_id'"
```

Firstly, you have opened the string with double quotes, `"`. but are attempting to close them with single quotes, `'`. You can't close double quotes with single quotes, so the quotes are just becoming part of the string, same with the `cat_id` variable name.

Secondly, after attempting to close the quotes you are not properly concatenating the variable `cat_id` onto the string. To concatenate strings in JS you need to use the `+` character.

So the `url` argument in your AJAX call should be:

```
url: "http://solucase.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=" + cat_id
```

Or

```
url: 'http://solucase.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=' + cat_id
```

Either will work.

Also note that you are not adding anything after the category ID, so you don't need to open and close the quotes again.

Comment: No problem. If it helped mark the answer as 'accepted' so future visitors can see that the issue was resolved.